# WCF ServiceContract and SOAP response not called *Response

Tags: wcf, soap, servicecontract, operationcontract

I'm writing a SOAP consumer using WCF.

In the following WCF service contract, WCF expects that the response has a Body and an element called **HelloResponse**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface HelloService
{
    string Hello(string input);
}
```

On the service I'm calling, it is actually called **HelloResult**. How can I tell WCF this, without using MessageContracts? I tried combinations and variations of the following, but without success.

```
...
[OperationContract(ReplyAction = "HelloResult")]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "HelloResult")]
...
```

Comment: Does the service not have metadata from which you can generate a client?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the service operation Hello(string) returns a string then why not just create a channel and call the operation directly rather than worrying about messages?